# Locating a row in pandas based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, pandas-loc

So this is a common question but I cant find an answer that fits this particular scenario.

So I have a `Dataframe` with columns for genres eg "Drama, Western" and one hot encoded versions of the genres so for the drama and western there is a **1** in both columns but where its just Western genre its **1** for that column **0** for drama.

I want a filtered dataframe containing rows with only Western and no other genre. Im trying to oversample for a model as it is a minor class but I don't want to increase other genre counts as a byproduct

There are multiple rows so I can't use the index and there are multiple genres so I can't use a condition like `df[(df['Western']==1) & (df['Drama']==0)` without having to account for **24** genres.

```
Index | Genre           |  Drama | Western | Action | genre 4 |
   0    Drama, Western       1        1         0         0
   1    Western              0        1         0         0
   3    Action, Western      0        1         1         0
```

Comment: what are the conditions, can you add the expected output.

Comment: @Abhi_J I want a filtered dataframe containing rows with only Western and no other genre. Im trying to oversample for a model as it is a minor class but I don't want to increase other genre counts as a byproduct.

Comment: `onehot[onehot.Western & onehot.sum(1) == 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want those rows where only 'Western' is 1, i.e. the genre is only Western, nothing else.

Why do you have to use the encoded columns then? Just use the original 'Genre' column where the data is in string format. No need to overcomplicate things.

```
new_df = df[df['Genre']=='Western']
```

Comment: I can't believe I didnt just try this I thought for sure it would also return Drama, Western etc.... I'm embarrassed of myself for this one...thanks though

Comment: @Goldenhigh No worries! We all have had moments like that, when we can't see what's right in front of us :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make a column_list of genre like `column_list = ['Western', 'Drama', 'Action', ...]` and find its sum, if its sum is equal to 1, then we can compare the value of 'Western' column if it is equal to 1. Try this out, this should return the Index of row where only 'Western' is 1:

```
column_list = ['Western', 'Drama', 'Action', ...]
df.loc[df[column_list].sum(axis=1)==1 and df['Western']==1, 'Index']
```

Comment: AI will also try this as its along the lines of what I thought I would have to do and I can learn from it but you'll see my embarrassment below at how easy the solution was...

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't got the `Genre` column, you could do

```
df[
    (df['Western']==1)
    &
    (df[df.columns.difference(['Western'])]==0).all(axis=1)
]
```